# Derivative of a definite integral with fraction

Tags: calculus, integration

I think I may be on the right track but need some help pulling my thoughts together. I have this problem:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int^{\frac{1}{t}}_0 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

So, I believe I want to spread this out via the chain rule where $u = 1+x^2$ and $du = 2x\,dx$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. I think I can spread out the integral so that
$$\int^{\frac{1}{t}}_0 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx$$

Then is the first multiplier $\frac{1}{u}$ while the second is just $du$?

Comment: Easiest: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Chain Rule.  But in this example the integration is easy, so we can integrate then differentiate. But you really should do it using FTC. You are not on the right track.

Comment: @Integrator, Thanks! Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making exactly the usual mistake: thinking you need to find the integral to do this kind of problem.  You don't.
$$
y = \int_0^{1/t}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}.
$$
$$
y = \int_0^u \frac{dx}{1+x^2},\qquad u = \frac 1 t.
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dt}}^{\text{Chain rule}} = \frac 1 {1+u^2}\cdot\frac{d}{dt} \frac 1 t & = \frac 1 {1+u^2} \cdot \left(\frac {-1}{t^2}\right) \\[10pt]
& =  \frac1{1+\frac 1{t^2}} \cdot\left(\frac{-1}{t^2}\right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac{-1}{t^2+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Michael Hardy, what is instead of 0, the lower constraint had been t?

Comment: Then you could write $\displaystyle\int_t^{1/t} = \int_t^0+\int_0^{1/t}$ $\displaystyle=-\int_0^t+\int_0^{1/t}$.  You would treat the second integral as above and the first more directly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, Part 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) combined with the Chain Rule:

$$
{d\over dt}\int_0^{1/t}{1\over 1+x^2}\,dx={1\over 1+x^2}\Bigg|_{x=1/t}\cdot{d\over dt}(1/t)={1\over 1+(1/t)^2}\cdot (-t^{-2})={-t^{-2}\over 1+t^{-2}}={-1\over t^2+1}
$$

Comment: thanks. What about the lower constraint on the integral 0

Comment: According to the FTOC part 1, the lower limit plays no role so long as it is constant.